# Extraer valores de un json con sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Tengo un json y necesito extraer un valor con comando sed.
(No puedo usar jq pues no puedo instalarlo en el entorno que estoy)
El problema que tengo es que he conseguido extraer los valores que están entre comillas pero no si no lo están.

Este es el resultado del json:

```
{"value1":5.0,"value2":2.5,"value3":"2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z","modifier":[]}
```

Con el siguiente comando:

```
sed -e 's/^.*"value3":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

Me da el resultado:

019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z

Como puedo sacar el “value2” que seria 2.5?

Gracias!

Comment: Has probado a cambiar en el comando `value3` por `value2`?

Comment: Claro, sucede que tu regexp está diseñada para extraer los valores que vienen entre comillas dobles. Debes modificar la regexp. No soy experto en regexp. Pero debes tirar por allí. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es bastante mas fácil con `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '"value2":\K[^,]+' foo.json 
2.5
```

Por el caso general, donde tienes un `key` y un `valor` donde el valor puede ser entre `"` o no, puedes usar: `"key":"?\K[^,}]+`. Es decir:

```
$ grep -oP '"value1":\K"?[^,}]+' foo.json
5.0
$ grep -oP '"value2":\K"?[^,}]+' foo.json
2.5
$ grep -oP '"value3":\K"?[^,}]+' foo.json
"2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z"
$ grep -oP '"modifier":\K"?[^,}]+' foo.json
[]
```

#### Explicacion

- `grep -oP` : el `-o` hace que `grep` solo imprime la parte de cada linea que hace match con la expresión regular. El `-P` activa las Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, que nos dan el `\K`.
- `"key":\K"?[^,}]+`: El `\K` quiere decir "to lo que fue encontrado hasta ahora no deperia considerarse como parte del 'match'". Entonces no lo vemos en la salida de `grep -o`. Aquí, se busca por `"key":`, y se ignora lo que fue encontrado. Después busca por 0 o uno `"` (`"?`) y, finalmente, los mas caracteres posibles que no sean ni `,` ni `}` (`[^,}]+`).

---

Si quieres mucho hacerlo con `sed`, lo equivalente seria:

```
sed -E 's/.*value1"?:([^,}]+).*/\1/' foo.json 
sed -E 's/.*value2"?:([^,}]+).*/\1/' foo.json 
sed -E 's/.*value3"?:([^,}]+).*/\1/' foo.json 
sed -E 's/.*modifier"?:([^,}]+).*/\1/' foo.json
```

---

IMPORTANTE: las dos soluciones asumen que no hay ningun `,` dentro de ningun valor de tu JSON. Esto no será siempre el caso.

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren varias maneras de hacerlo además de con `sed`.

### Con Python

```
$ python -c 'import json,sys
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f: print(json.load(f)[sys.argv[2]])' a.json value3
2019-10-24T15:26:00.000Z
```

De esta manera, únicamente tendrías que cambiar el nombre de la clave en el segundo argumento.

Esta forma me resulta la mejor de todas, puesto que se usa una herramienta (`load`) específica para el tratamiento de este tipo de datos. Sólo habría que ver que tengas instalado python, que creo que en muchas distribuciones ya viene por defecto.

### Con grep

A diferencia de la respuesta de @terdon yo propongo un *positive lookahead* y un *positive lookbehind*

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=value2(":)).*?(?=(,"|}))' a.json
```

Entonces lo único que hay que cambiar es el valor de la clave "value2". Puse entre paréntesis `(\":)` por el único motivo de separarlo del nombre de la clave y así hacerlo "más legible" puesto que sólo se cambia la clave y no se mira lo que esté dentro del paréntesis por lo que tu mente no tiene que hacer un esfuerzo mínimo extra :) . Cuestión personal.

### Con Perl

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$&\n" if /(?<=value2(":))(.*?)(?=(,"|}))/' a.json
```

Es semejante a la anterior salvo que aquí `$&` indica el valor que se capturó en el grupo.

### Con awk

```
$ awk -v valor=value2 'BEGIN { FS=":"; RS="," }{
    if (index($1, valor)!=0) { 
        gsub(/(^.*?["]:|{|})/,"",$0) 
        print $0 
    } 
}' a.json
```

Aquí separo los campos por el caracter `:`, separo las líneas por las comas y luego reviso si el primer campo contiene lo almacenado en la variable `valor`, la cual tiene el valor de "value2", ya que se lo pasé con el parámetro `-v valor=value2`. Después, al renglón completo (`$0`) le elimino lo que entre el inicio del registro y dos puntos (`:`), y llaves para luego imprimir lo demás.

Como verás, estas versiones son "poco poderosas", así que sólo sirven para casos específicos con archivos json sin llaves, etc. Pero para un json como el que mostraste, funciona "bien".